# How command id differs from infrastructure message id?

Tags: events, command, microservices, correlation, cqrs

I am thinking about something what is connected a little bit with CQRS. There is a pattern Request-Reply. In example of HTTP transport into header we put **Request-Id** for at least tracking purposes. In my case monitoring between different microservices. If incoming request contains it than rewrite is done to **Correlation-Id** header. As I think this is done on transport layer (infrastructure). Question is if that Request-Id (sometimes named as Message-Id) should be delivered from business layer in example directly from command that we are executing - some mechinics does this auto-magically - like ICommand requires that Id is present? 
Or it's totally different thing that exists only in infrastructure layer (transport)? If yes, than how to correlate transport id with business command id? At least one log/trace/track thing has to be placed with both identifiers? Is there pattenr that I missed? Moreover what you think CorrelationId should be in business command or not?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO concepts such as correlation id, causation id, request id, message id, etc belong to the infrastructure layer as they are not part of the business rules.

However, I've added a *metadata* attribute to my *Command* and *Event* objects to save this kind of info which helps me to manage the correlation and causation relationship between commands and events.

By having this *metadata* attribute in the form of an associative array (hash map, dictionary or whatever key-value format), you leave your code opened to persist any tracking info you may need in the future without polluting your Application and Domain layers too much.

Comment: I completely agree about having this type of "metadata" in an infrastructure layer. I don't think they should be included in the message, however. In my case, they are packaged in a single object that is separate from the message being processed. Event and Command Handlers always receive it. Sagas use the information to route commands. Aggregates don't receive any of it since they are not aware of the existence of a messaging concept. In this way, we isolate the domain from the implementation which happens to use a messaging layer.

Comment: Totally agree with your definition. I want to extend my answer with a bit of pseudo code to make it more representative

Comment: @mgonzalezbaile that would be great!